# How to strip first column from 2D lists?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Trying to strip string from 2D list but only in the first column

My attempt:

```
list = [[x.strip('this') for x in y[0]] for y in list]
```

Example list:

```
[["apple this","juice this"],
["orange this","lemonade this"],
["kiwi this","punch this"]]
```

Wanted result:

```
[["apple","juice this"],
["orange","lemonade this"],
["kiwi","punch this"]]
```

Stripping only "this" from first column but not second.

Preferably not even checking other columns.

Comment: Please provide your desired output for `list`, along what what `list` was before you mentioned it in the code posted above.

Comment: What is `y` and `list`?

Comment: Provided an example now.

Comment: @Augis added an answer for it now! cheers

Comment: What is the current output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split()` and `zip()`:

```
ee = [["apple this","juice this"],
["orange this","lemonade this"],
["kiwi this","punch this"]]

splitted = [x[0].split()[0] for x in ee]  # ['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi']
later_lst = [x[1] for x in ee]  # ['juice this', 'lemonade this', 'punch this']

print([list(l) for l in zip(splitted, later_lst)])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['apple', 'juice this'], ['orange', 'lemonade this'], ['kiwi', 'punch this']]
```

one-liner:

```
print([list(l) for l in zip([x[0].split()[0] for x in ee], [x[1] for x in ee])])
```

**EDIT**:

Shorter-version:

```
print([[x[0].split()[0], x[1]] for x in ee])
```

Comment: Shorter version is pretty much exactly what I needed, kind sad though that universal solution isn't available.

Comment: Some might say that this is the universal solution, a tool that helps you build a list by modifying every element from another list... the thing is that you needed a very specific solution which is not the most common of requests, yet it can be done easily

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
list = [[(x if i else x.strip()) for i,x in enumerate(y)] for y in list]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```py
list = [[x.strip('strip this') if j==0 else x for j,x in enumerate(y)] for y in list]
```

Comment: Notice passing `'strip this'` to `str.strip` will not look for an exact match, rather it will take the parameter as a collection of characters to be matched in any order and length, e.g. `'kiwi this'` will be stripped of `'i this'` (because all these letters and the space are included in the parameter) and return `'kiw'`... read about it in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: yes but that was not the question asked by the questioner. he just wanted to strip whatever he want from a 2d list.

Comment: Copied from OP... "Wanted result ... `["kiwi",...`"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This line of code will remove

```
[[i.replace(' this',''), j] for i, j in a]
```